# How can I pass a nested key to a map as a variable?

Tags: elixir

I have a map and a key. When a key is a simple literal such a string or atom, I can retrieve a value from a map - it's simple.

How can I retrieve a nested value from a map: how can I create such a nested key and pass it to a map?

Something like this:

```
my_map = %{a: 1, b: %{c: 234}}

my_nest_key = ?????

my_nest_val = my_map[my_nest_key]
# ===> 234
```

Comment: No, you can't access nested value with one single bracket access.

Comment: @Dogbert not necessarily with a single bracket. Maybe via "Map.some_func(...)" somehow?

Comment: Yes, `get_in(my_map, [:b, :c])`.

Comment: @Dogbert -- I have a variable!

Comment: How do you mean @Jorudin?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this?

```
iex> my_map = %{a: 1, b: %{c: 234}}
...> my_nest_key = "b.c"
...> keys = my_nest_key |> String.split(".") |> Enum.map(&String.to_existing_atom/1)
[:b, :c]
...> get_in(my_map, keys)
234
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_existing_atom/1

Comment: You put the warning of the `to_atom` function into your answer, but why didn't you bother to actually use `to_existing_atom/1`? Since OP wants to access atoms which already exist, it's better to use `to_existing_atom/1`, as it doesn't create new atoms. There's no need to create new atoms if the key doesn't exist anyway.

Comment: Good idea, fixed